# Annotation is not visible on some compilers

Tags: java, android, annotations

i have quite a funny problem.
I have defined annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyAnnot {

}
```

I have:

```
public interface F<T>{
  public void onFinish(T param);
}

public abstract class Foo<T> implements F<T>{
}
```

Also:

```
public class Bar extends Foo<Drawable>{
  @Override
  @MyAnnot  
  public void onFinish(Drawable d){
    // ...
  }
}
```

And:

```
public class FooBar extends Bar{

  @Override
  @MyAnnot  
  public void onFinish(Drawable d){
    // ...
  }
}
```

In one of methods in Foo I added:

```
Method method = this.getClass().getMethod("onFinish", Object.class);
if (method.isAnnotationPresent( MyAnnot.class )){
  //Do sth
}
```

I'm using this in android project, on one of my computers this works fine, but on second isAnnotationPresent always returns false. Application was run in both cases by IntelliJ Idea, on the same phone.

Additionally if i use `this.getClass().getMethod("onFinish", Drawable.class);` it works on all computers.

Comment: I would say that this points more to an issue with the classpath that with the compiler itself.

Comment: Hey, i forgot about interface, not should look as it is in my project.

@Aubin in public class Bar and FooBar there can't be abstract method, since they are implemented classes. :)

Comment: I try to compile your code. I've some explanation... wait a minute

Comment: I'm not going anywhere, installing IDE on my GF's computer to check something.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to find the correct argument to give to `getMethod( name, type )` using reflection.

Code:

```
package so;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public abstract class Foo<T> implements F<T> {

   public static Class<?> getParameterizedType( Class<?> clazz ) {
      Type t = clazz.getGenericSuperclass();
      while( t != Object.class ) {
         if( t instanceof ParameterizedType ) {
            final Type[] actualTypeArguments =
               ((ParameterizedType)t).getActualTypeArguments();
            for( final Type arg : actualTypeArguments ) {
               return (Class<?>)arg;
            }
         }
         t = ((Class<?>)t).getGenericSuperclass();
      }
      throw new IllegalStateException();
   }

   public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception {
      final Object fooBar = new FooBar();
      final Class<?> clazz = fooBar.getClass();
      final Class<?> finishArgType = getParameterizedType( clazz );
      System.err.println( "finishArgType = " + finishArgType );
      final Method mth = clazz.getMethod( "onFinish", finishArgType );
      if( mth.isAnnotationPresent( MyAnnot.class )) {
         System.err.println( "Yessssssss!" );
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
finishArgType = class so.Drawable
Yessssssss!
```